# How to specify Association in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have got a domain class Track

```
class Track{
   static belongsTo = [createdBy: User, modifiedBy: User, Course]
}
```

But its giving me error, Finally i dont want  to have course object[course: Course] but only have to specify that it belongs to Course  [Course]. How to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the GORM associations a bit too extensively. `belongsTo` indicates ownership, and the GORM associations, in general, indicate more about the cascading relationship between objects than anything else.

If you only want to associate `User` with your `Track`, you just need to have the `createdBy` and `modifiedBy` fields, which don't need to be in any special sort of association. Then you would have `static belongsTo = [Course]` to show that the `Course` *owns* the `Track`, meaning that if you deleted the `Course`, that the `Track` would get deleted as well.

Here's the class I think you are looking for:

```
class Track {
    User createdBy
    User modifiedBy

    static belongsTo = [Course]
}
```

Comment: cdeszaq is spot on.  I'll just add that you will obviously have FK constraint issues to deal with if you need to delete a User.   But that is typical in these cases.

Comment: As @Gregg mentioned, deleting a User in this case will be a bit more painful, so I would suggest tucking the logic to "properly" delete a User (if you need to) inside a service.